# Access Css of Asp:Button

Tags: css

So I want all buttons on my site to look the same and I need to edit a CSS file for them.

I was just wondering how you can access the css style of all controls named `-asp:button`.

Ie. `Button { Font-size: 10px; }` or `#Button { Font-size: 10px; }`

So far this is not working.

Comment: "named"? Is this the button's `name=""` attribute, it's class, it's ID or what? Also, use something like Firebug or Chrome's DOM inspector to see what the generated HTML looks like, and base your selectors from there. You should try a lowercase `button` selector - see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most newer browsers support Attribute Selectors, so you could do something like

```
input[type="submit"] {
  //styles here
}
```

You'll get better all around support by applying a class though as others have suggested.

Comment: This will only work with CSS3 compatible browsers which are still a very small portion of the web user base.

Comment: @TerryR Attribute selectors started in CSS 2.1, and support is pretty broad actually. Ref: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: My apologies then, good to know.  Just a note: I think IE7 & 8 require a !DOCTYPE to be set for it to work.

Comment: You are correct about the !DOCTYPE. The support on them isn't perfect by any means, but it's pretty decent these days.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Button controls render as:

```
<input type="submit">
```

You will need to give them a css class name that you can control in your css file.

In server side code:

```
myButton.CssClass = "myClass"
```

OR in ASPX markup:

```
<asp:Button CssClass="myClass" runat="server" ... />
```

CSS:

```
.myClass { width: 100px }
```

Edit having seen your comment:

To modify all buttons across the site you need to use Javascript, the jQuery library is extremely effective at this.  If you were using jQuery you would just have this script on your Master page:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Select all "input" controls with the type of "submit" and add your class to them
    $(input[type="submit"]).addClass('myClass');
});
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without a css class on the button. Similar to setting the css of a table by #table

Comment: This is possible for sure and I am aware of this solution. I was just trying to use Css

Comment: input {  background-color: #666699;  } will give all inputs the background color specified.

Comment: You could use only CSS if your users were all on browsers that support CSS3 as it allows for selectors similar to jQuery.  Until then you will have to use some scripting as I have noted in my answer.

Comment: @BarryFranklin that will also affect textboxes, regular buttons and all other input controls which I sincerely doubt he wants.

Comment: @TerryR        At least they'll all be consistent! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can inclue [CSS class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) in your asp:button code to give them a class and control their style:

```
<asp:button CssClass="mybuttons" />
```

Then you can use this class to style those buttons:

```
.mybuttons{
font-size:10px;
}
```

If you had more buttons that are not ASP.NET generated then this class only applies to buttons that are ASP.NET generated not others.

Comment: This is what I know to do for sure. I am wanting to set css for any button anywhere in the site without setting a css class

Comment: Simply you can't do that. because ASP renders asp elements to HTML elements. So at at the end there is no difference between and asp button and an solid HTML button.

Comment: But if you want to apply a class to any ASP button you can do it in your master page code behind\

Comment: @JonathanO "I am wanting to set css for any button anywhere in the site without setting a css class".  The first part of that statement is the whole reason CSS was invented.  The second part completely contradicts it and there is no reasonable explanation for not using CSS if you want to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET you need to provide a CSS class for your buttons. If you call it "Button1" for example, your CSS declaration would be:

```
.Button1 {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An ASP button is rendered in HTML as an INPUT of type="submit"... you can access all the buttons by using INPUT, but of course there are other INPUTS as well...

```
input {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: larger;
background-color: Red;
```

}

Comment: can I do #input submit{css here?}